# How to create a WordPress plugin that registers a custom sidebar widget

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following use case. I have created a custom "search" functionality, all it is an input box that is using some API fetch and jquery magic.

[image: At first glace, just a search funtion]

Essentially, I want to add this search function into its own custom sidebar navigation widget via a plugin installation.

I wish to create a plugin that registers a custom "menu" sidebar widget.  The sidebar widget will drop this search functionality to were ever the widget is "dragged and dropped". The display is for only the front of the site. You know, how the default search widget works.

Some Facts:

- I have created a boiler plated plugin in wp-contents, it had a blank
  activate, deactivate and uninstall function within the mail plugin class and I have hooked the activate and deactivate button.
- The source code for the "custom search functionality" is within the
  same folder as the plugin.

Folder scheme looks like:

> - MBE PLUGIN
>
>   - index.php
>   - mbe-plugin.php
>   - api-search.html
>   - assets
>
>     - css
>     - scripts
>     - ETC

In my plugin.php file, what must I include in the "activation" function to achieve this?

This is my boilerplate plugin code... pretty empty

```
.

<?php
/**
 * @package MBEPlugin
 */
/*
Plugin Name: MBE Plugin
Plugin URI: http://localhost/mbeTest/plugin
Description: This plugin is for the search modal for MBE website. Project 'accordion'
Version: 1.0.0
Author: Erick Guerra
Author URI: http://bashs3c.com
License: GPLv2 or later
Text Domain: mbe-plugin
*/


// Secuirty measure, checks variable in env to ensure we are in WP
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    echo 'These are not the drones you are looking for!';
    exit;
}

class MbePlugin {

    function activate() {
        $searchHTML = file_get_contents(plugins_url('api-search.html', __FILE__));
        echo $searchHTML;
        // generate a CPT
        // Flush the rewrite rules
    }

    function deactivate() {
        // Flush rewrite rules
    }

    function uninstall() {
        // delete CPT
        // Delete all the plugin data from DB
    }

    function displaySearch() {
        $searchHTML = file_get_contents(plugins_url('api-search.html', __FILE__));
        echo $searchHTML;
    }

}

if (class_exists('MbePlugin')) {
    $mbePlugin = new MbePlugin();

}

//activation
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( $mbePlugin, 'activate' ) );
//deactivation
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array( $mbePlugin, 'deactivate' ) );
//uninstall

//
//add_actions('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'search_init');
```

Comment: Yep, the next step is to register a new widget via the [Widget API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API). Is that the answer you're expecting from us, though? A simple yes/no?

Comment: LOL I was hoping for some input as to which getter functions I would need to call to simply render the plugin code onto a custom navigation sidebar for display front-site. I could see why the confusing, being that the last question is open-ended, but if you read the entire question again, you might gather that It's not a "yes or no" I'm looking for.